# How to get the price per unit based on the price of an item at the highest rate

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have multiple tables join together to get the latest **Transaction Date, Stock Code, Stock Name, UOM Code, Rate, UOM Price, Current Balance** for an item.

The problem is to get the **UOM Price** for the highest rate is easy, but what if I want to get the **UOM Price Per Unit** based on the highest rate which is by doing this formula `UOM Price / Rate = Price Per Unit`

In my mind, I want to do like this :

1. If an item have multiple **UOM Codes**, then check if there are multiple rates.
2. If **Yes**, then do the formula and put the value to the lowest rate as it is the price per unit for the item.
3. If **No**, then no need to do the formula.

Here is my code

```
SELECT *
FROM(
    SELECT 
        TransactionDate,    -- from StockTransactions Table
        DocumentCode,       -- from StockTransactions Table
        StockCode,          -- from Stocks Table
        StockName,          -- from Stocks Table
        UOMCode,            -- from UOMs Table      
        Rate,               -- from UOMs Table  
        st.UOMPriceExcLandingCost as UOMPrice, -- from StockTransactions Table  
        FORMAT(CurrentBalance, 'N4') AS CurrentBalance, --from stocks table
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY StockCode, UOMCode ORDER BY TransactionDate DESC) RN -- sort from latest to oldest stock transactions based on stockcode and UOMCode
    FROM UOMs us
        LEFT JOIN Stocks s ON s.Id = us.StockId -- join Stocks Table
        LEFT JOIN StockTransactions st ON st.StockId = us.StockId   -- join StockTransactions Table
        LEFT JOIN StockPurchasePriceHistory spph on spph.Stock = us.StockId
    WHERE 
        st.TransactionDate BETWEEN '2000-01-01' AND GETDATE()   --get result from specific transaction date in StockTransations Table
        AND st.Qty > 0
        AND st.DocumentCode NOT LIKE 'SA%'  --get all documentcode except documentcode that start with SA in StockTransations Table 
        OR st.DocumentCode  LIKE 'SA1503%'  --get all documentcode that start with SA1503 in StockTransations Table
        AND st.DocumentCode NOT LIKE 'CN%'  --get all documentcode except documentcode that start with CN in StockTransations Table     
    GROUP BY 
        --group columns that might have multple records with different stock transactions date
        TransactionDate,
        DocumentCode,
        StockCode,
        StockName,
        UOMCode,
        Rate,
        st.UOMPriceExcLandingCost,
        CurrentBalance
) StockInquiry
WHERE 
    RN = 1  -- get latest date in stockpurchasepricehistory table
    AND StockCode = 'WRC3MM'  -- for checking purpose only
ORDER BY StockCode ASC -- sort result by stockcode in ascending order
```

Here is my output

[image: Output]

Here is the sample of the Database : [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/a9cac4/1)

Here is the sample of the Database extract using ApexSQL = [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BUkvJcHbYEvIBmPxd9W0aD_QHBm7gl45/view?usp=sharing)

The output should be :

1. If METER then it should be `230 / 305 = 0.7540 Price Per Unit`
2. If ROLL/305 then it should be `230`

If you look at the **UOM Price** right now, it is getting the highest price for the highest rate.
It is possible to solve this even if an item have different **UOM Code**?

Comment: Please show sample data (as DDL+DML).

Comment: And show any other data as tabular text (not images).

Comment: @DaleK I have updated my post for the database sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to modify the join to [StockTransactions] so that you include the UOMid in the join logic PLUS you can also include the row_number() calculation in as a subquery so that you only join to the latest rows of that table:

```
/* modified */
    SELECT 
        TransactionDate,    -- from StockTransactions Table
        DocumentCode,       -- from StockTransactions Table
        StockCode,          -- from Stocks Table
        StockName,          -- from Stocks Table
        UOMCode,            -- from UOMs Table      
        Rate,               -- from UOMs Table  
        st.UOMPriceExcLandingCost as UOMPrice, -- from StockTransactions Table
        FORMAT(CurrentBalance, 'N4') AS CurrentBalance, --from stocks table
        st.RN
    FROM UOMs us
        INNER JOIN Stocks s ON s.Id = us.StockId    -- join Stocks Table
        INNER JOIN (
                select *
                    , row_number() over(partition by StockId, UOMid order by TransactionDate DESC) as rn
                from StockTransactions
                ) st ON st.StockId = us.StockId AND st.UOMid = us.id AND rn = 1
    WHERE 
        st.TransactionDate BETWEEN '2000-01-01' AND GETDATE()   --get result from specific transaction date in StockTransations Table
        AND st.Qty > 0
        AND (st.DocumentCode NOT LIKE 'SA%' --get all documentcode except documentcode that start with SA in StockTransations Table 
          OR st.DocumentCode  LIKE 'SA1503%')   --get all documentcode that start with SA1503 in StockTransations Table
        AND st.DocumentCode NOT LIKE 'CN%'  --get all documentcode except documentcode that start with CN in StockTransations Table     
;
```

result:

```
+-----------------+--------------+-----------+--------------------------------+-----------+------+----------+----------------+----+
| TransactionDate | DocumentCode | StockCode |           StockName            |  UOMCode  | Rate | UOMPrice | CurrentBalance | RN |
+-----------------+--------------+-----------+--------------------------------+-----------+------+----------+----------------+----+
| 2015-03-01      | SA1503/388   | WRC3MM    | WIRE ROPE GI C/W COVER 3MMX5MM | METER     |    1 |     0.75 |        22.3000 |  1 |
| 2016-05-14      | BIL1605/065  | WRC3MM    | WIRE ROPE GI C/W COVER 3MMX5MM | ROLL/305M |  305 |      230 |        22.3000 |  1 |
+-----------------+--------------+-----------+--------------------------------+-----------+------+----------+----------------+----+
```

[demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/a9cac4/8)

Also, I think you need parentheses in the where clause to control the OR, I don't know if I have introduced these correctly however.

Comment: By doing this, you are grouping the transaction document code instead of grouping the UOM Code. I just need to get the price per unit of the latest transaction of each item if the item have multiple UOM Codes.

Comment: The query does not use group by at all so I'm not sure what you mean by that comment. It strikes me that the way you are linking initially ignores the UOM relationship which I would say is there for a reason in the StockTransactions table and ignoring it is why you are getting undesirable results. If I'm incorrect so be it. I have done what appears to me to be logical and maybe somebody else can comprehend what is required.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I will use your solution as my reference to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved my problem thanks to Paul Maxwell solution

Here is the final code, I'm not sure if it is the correct way to do it but it works

```
SELECT
    DocDate,
    DocCode,
    StockCode,
    FORMAT((Price / us.Rate), 'N4') AS PricePerUnit,
    UOMCode AS LastPurchasePriceUOM,
    FORMAT(Price, 'N4') AS LastPurchasePrice,
    FORMAT(CurrentBalance, 'N4') AS Balance,
    st.RN
FROM StockPurchasePriceHistory spph
    INNER JOIN Stocks s ON spph.Stock = s.Id    
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT 
            Id, 
            Rate, 
            UOMCode 
        FROM UOMs 
        WHERE 
        UOMs.Description IS NULL
    ) us ON spph.UOM = us.Id
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT
            StockId,
            UOMId,
            TransactionDate, 
            DocumentCode, 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY StockId, UOMId ORDER BY TransactionDate DESC) AS RN 
        FROM StockTransactions
    ) st ON st.StockId = spph.Stock AND st.UOMId = us.Id AND RN = 1
WHERE 
    st.TransactionDate BETWEEN '2000-01-01' AND GETDATE()
    AND (st.DocumentCode NOT LIKE 'SA%' OR st.DocumentCode LIKE 'SA1503%')
    AND st.DocumentCode NOT LIKE 'CN%'
ORDER BY StockCode ASC
```

Sample here : [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/7c778/3)

Output is like this :

| DocDate | DocCode | StockCode | PricePerUnit | LastPurchasePriceUOM | LastPurchasePrice | Balance | RN |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2016-05-13 | BIL1605/065 | WRC3MM | 0.7541 | ROLL/305M | 230.0000 | 22.3000 | 1 |